# I want to know Why my code makes blank rows between XMLinformation?

Tags: python, xml, xlsxwriter

Each information in XML appears with 16 blanks.

I am using python 3.7.1. I added "row += 1" in "for k in tree.iter('bar'):"
However, only last XML information appears in the second row.

XML code(estate(2).xml):

```
<bar>
<F169 id="F169.777568">
    <pos>193239.0950999996 456314.7006000001</pos>
    <X_CRDNT>193239.0951</X_CRDNT>
    <Y_CRDNT>456314.7006</Y_CRDNT>
    <PNU>1138010600100330007</PNU>
    <LD_CPSG_CODE>11380</LD_CPSG_CODE>
    <LD_EMD_LI_CODE>10600</LD_EMD_LI_CODE>
    <REGSTR_SE_CODE>1</REGSTR_SE_CODE>
    <MNNM>0033</MNNM>
    <SLNO>0007</SLNO>
    <SYS_REGIST_NO>113802018000058</SYS_REGIST_NO>
    <STTUS_SE_CODE>1</STTUS_SE_CODE>
    <LAST_SEQ_NO>1</LAST_SEQ_NO>
    <BSNM_CMPNM>½ºÅ¸°øÀÎÁß°³»ç»ç¹«¼Ò</BSNM_CMPNM>
    <EMPLYM_CO>1</EMPLYM_CO>
    <FRST_REGIST_DT>2018-11-04T09:59:00</FRST_REGIST_DT>
</F169>

<F169 id="F169.777569">
    <pos>193239.0950999996 456314.7006000001</pos>
    <X_CRDNT>193239.0952</X_CRDNT>
    <Y_CRDNT>456314.7007</Y_CRDNT>
    <PNU>1138010600100330007</PNU>
    <LD_CPSG_CODE>11380</LD_CPSG_CODE>
    <LD_EMD_LI_CODE>10600</LD_EMD_LI_CODE>
    <REGSTR_SE_CODE>1</REGSTR_SE_CODE>
    <MNNM>0033</MNNM>
    <SLNO>0007</SLNO>
    <SYS_REGIST_NO>113802018000058</SYS_REGIST_NO>
    <STTUS_SE_CODE>1</STTUS_SE_CODE>
    <LAST_SEQ_NO>1</LAST_SEQ_NO>
    <BSNM_CMPNM>½ºÅ¸°øÀÎÁß°³»ç»ç¹«¼Ò</BSNM_CMPNM>
    <EMPLYM_CO>1</EMPLYM_CO>
    <FRST_REGIST_DT>2018-11-04T09:59:00</FRST_REGIST_DT>
</F169>
</bar>
```

python code:

```
            import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
            import xlsxwriter

            workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("parse.xlsx")
            worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
            bold = workbook.add_format({"bold":1})
            tree = ET.parse('estate(2).xml')

            col = 0
            i=0
            row = 0
            plus_row = 1

            print(tree.getiterator())

            for k in tree.iter('bar'):

                for j in k.iter():

                    print(j.text)
                    worksheet.write(row, col, j.findtext("pos"))
                    worksheet.write(row, col+1, j.findtext("X_CRDNT"))
                    worksheet.write(row, col+2, j.findtext("Y_CRDNT"))
                    worksheet.write(row, col+3, j.findtext("PNU"))
                    worksheet.write(row, col+4, j.findtext("LD_CPSG_CODE"))
                    worksheet.write(row, col+5, j.findtext("LD_EMD_LI_CODE"))
                    worksheet.write(row, col+6, j.findtext("REGSTR_SE_CODE"))
                    worksheet.write(row, col+7, j.findtext("MNNM"))
                    worksheet.write(row, col+8, j.findtext("SLNO"))
                    worksheet.write(row, col+9, j.findtext("SYS_REGIST_NO"))
                    worksheet.write(row, col+10, j.findtext("BSNM_CMPNM"))
                    worksheet.write(row, col+11, j.findtext("EMPLYM_CO"))
                    worksheet.write(row, col+12, j.findtext("FRST_REGIST_DT"))
                    if j.get("ETC_ADRES") is not "true":
                        worksheet.write(row, col+13, j.findtext("ETC_ADRES"))

                    row += 1

                """
                j = 0
                if i is 0:
                    row += 1
                    i+=1
                elif i >= 1 and i<=16:
                    continue
                elif i > 16:
                    i = 0
                """

            print(k.iter())
            #convert to .xlsx
            worksheet.write("A1", 'pos', bold)
            worksheet.write("B1", 'X_CRDNT', bold)
            worksheet.write("C1", 'Y_CRDNT', bold)
            worksheet.write("D1", 'PNU', bold)
            worksheet.write("E1", 'LD_CPSG_CODE', bold)
            worksheet.write("F1", 'LD_EMD_LI_CODE', bold)
            worksheet.write("G1", 'REGSTR_SE_CODE', bold)
            worksheet.write("H1", 'MNNM', bold)
            worksheet.write("I1", 'SLNO', bold)
            worksheet.write("J1", 'SYS_REGIST_NO', bold)
            worksheet.write("K1", 'BSNM_CMPNM', bold)
            worksheet.write("L1", 'EMPLYM_CO', bold)
            worksheet.write("M1", 'FRST_REGIST_DT', bold)


            workbook.close()
```

This python code will write parse.xlsx information of estate(2).xml 
Information in XML appears in Excel file without blank.
[excel file with blanks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YH9DL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written your code contains two problems:

1. In the following nested loops, `k` iterates through all of the `bar` elements (of which there is only one), and then `j` iterates through all descendant elements of `k`:

   ```
       for k in tree.iter('bar'):

           for j in k.iter():

               print(j.text)
               # ...
   ```

   When `j` is one of the `<f169>` elements, a row of data gets read from its child elements.  However, `j` also runs through the descendant elements of the `<bar>` element (`<pos>`, `<X_CRDNT>`, `<Y_CRDNT>`) as well.  These other elements don't have any child elements, so if `j` is one of these, `j.findtext('MNNM')` will return nothing.  Hence you get a blank row for each descendant element of `<f169>`.

   The fix is to replace `for j in k.iter():` with `for j in k.iter('f169'):`.  This way, `j` only iterates through the `<f169>` elements.
2. At the end you write the headers over the first row of the data.  Avoid this problem by setting `row = 1` instead of `row = 0` at the start.